# Stopping Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, file

I have an application having a thread which runs continously,writing to a file.And it should terminate on a button click.But this results in flooding of Exceptions which forces the application to terminate.I tried using stop() function,but that doesn't work.Can any one suggest a method(code if possible) to safely terminate the thread and close the file.

Comment: The safest way is always having the threat terminate itself. I think it maybe a better idea to look into what is causing the exception. Would you mind pasting in the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threading in Java is cooperative: you can not stop a thread from outside, you can only signal it to stop an then thread stops itself (i.e. exits the run method).

To signal it to stop, just have a boolean field `running=true` which thread checks in it's main loop. When `running==false` thread exits the `run()` method.

In your particular case it could be a bit trickier depending how you read data to be written to file. Do you use any blocking read calls to read the data?

Comment: Simple and effective...that did the trick...thks Peter...u saved my day!!

Answer (score 0):

For the thread:

```
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        // write each line to file here
    {
    // close file
}
```

For the button's `onClick()` add:

```
running=false;
myThread.join(); // enclose in try/catch and while loop appropriately to ensure the thread ends
```